# http authentication using request module of nodejs returning undefined body

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, http-authentication

Trying to hit the following [http-auth](https://github.com/gevorg/http-auth) code:

```
var auth = require("http-auth");
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Authentication required",
    file: __dirname + "/../htpasswd" 
});
http.createServer(basic, onRequest).listen(port);
```

The following is the code snippet that's hitting the above logic with [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) of nodejs:

```
var request = require('request'),
    username = "username",
    password = "password",
    url = "http://localhost:3000/",
    auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

request(
    {
        url : url,
        headers : {
            "Authorization" : auth
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("body "+body);
        console.log("response "+response);
        console.log("error "+error);
    }
);
```

Output:

response : **undefined**

body     : **undefined**

error    : **socket hang up**

**Stack trace:**

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:203:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:288:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
```

onRequest method:

```
module.exports.start = function(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response){

        // response.write("welcome "+request.user+"!");

        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        route(handle, pathname, request, response);
    }// on request ends here
```

onRequest is called from app.js like this:

```
var router = require("./lib/router.js");
var handle = {}
    handle["/add"] = requestHandler.addMethod;
    handle["/delete"] = requestHandler.deleteMethod;
    handle["/edit"] = requestHandler.editMethod;
    handle["/search"] = requestHandler.searchMethod;
    console.log(router.route);

    server.start(router.route, handle);
```

router.js

```
"use strict";

var url = require("url");

module.exports.route = function(handle, pathname, request, response) {
    if(typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](request, response);
    } else {
        console.log("no request handler found for "+pathname);
    }// else ends here
}// route ends here
```

Method from the handler (requestHandler):

```
module.exports.addMethod = function (req, res) {
    body = "";
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        body = JSON.parse(body);   
        databaseConnection.collection("productList").insert(body, function(err,data) {
            if(err){
                res.writeHead(400, {"contentType":"application/JSON"});
                var failedRes = JSON.stringify({ 
                    error : {
                        text : "Failed to add product"
                    }
                });
                res.end(faileRes);
                return;
            }// error handling
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/JSON"});
            var finalId = data.ops[0]._id;
            var successRes = JSON.stringify({ 
                data: {
                    id : finalId
                },
                error : {
                    code : 0,
                    text : "Product added successfully"
                }
            });
            res.end(successRes);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace?

Comment: yup, I'm editing the question to include stack trace

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the error. Can you post the `onRequest` method?

Comment: added onRequest method

Comment: The `onRequest` method uses the `route` method but I do not know the definition of the `route` method. Could you post this as well?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've improved my solution but there's one part missing: I don't know the function signature for any of the methods in `handler`. I can guess but you need an exact answer. Could you post the code for any of the methods in `handler` ?

Comment: ya sure. thanks for your effort. I'll do one think, I'll create a repo on github and share the link with you

Comment: I've added a sample method from the  handler above in the question. Also I've created a repo on github, if it helps: https://github.com/Riser101/node

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of a `JSON.parse` error on the server. The `body` object is a string but it is not a valid JSON string. This causes the line:

```
JSON.parse(body);
```

to throw an error on the server (if not data was sent):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)

or, if data was sent:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>       at Object.parse (native)

Either of these errors cause the server to crash and, consequently, the client to report the `socket hang up` error.

To resolve this, you'll need to send the data to the server as JSON. To do this with the `request` module:

```
request.post(url, {
  headers: {
      "Authorization" : auth
  },
  json: {
    message: 'Hello'
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("body "+body);
    console.log("response "+response);
    console.log("error "+error);
});
```

Comment: It can't be true, because I'm not even the hitting the addMethod route. And I've checked it out too.